# Convert recurring JSON names to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following string...

```
{
    "Qualifications[0].DegreeType": "Degree Type 1",
    "Qualifications[0].Classification": "Clasification 1",
    "Qualifications[0].CourseTitle": "Course Title 1",
    "Qualifications[0].YearOfAward": "2018",
    "Qualifications[0].AwardingInstitution": "Awarding institution 1",
    "Qualifications[1].DegreeType": "Degree Type 2",
    "Qualifications[1].Classification": "Classification 2",
    "Qualifications[1].CourseTitle": "Course Title 2",
    "Qualifications[1].YearOfAward": "2019",
    "Qualifications[1].AwardingInstitution": "Awarding Institution 2",
    ... and so on...
 }
```

Does anybody know of a simple way to convert this into a javascript object so that I can effectively just go...

```
$(Qualifications).each(i, v){
    //do stuff on whatever property of Qualifications[i]
}
```

Only way I can think of would be using string manipulation and something like below but it's going to need a lot of custom code checking mappings for each property and I'm after something more generic and simple....

```
    let i = 0;
    while (Qualifications[" + i +"].whateverProperty..) {
        //add to object array
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the keys and reduce the path by walking the given object.

If no object exist, create a new property with the name, or an array. Later assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (o, k, i, kk) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {
        "Qualifications[0].DegreeType": "Degree Type 1",
        "Qualifications[0].Classification": "Clasification 1",
        "Qualifications[0].CourseTitle": "Course Title 1",
        "Qualifications[0].YearOfAward": "2018",
        "Qualifications[0].AwardingInstitution": "Awarding institution 1",
        "Qualifications[1].DegreeType": "Degree Type 2",
        "Qualifications[1].Classification": "Classification 2",
        "Qualifications[1].CourseTitle": "Course Title 2",
        "Qualifications[1].YearOfAward": "2019",
        "Qualifications[1].AwardingInstitution": "Awarding Institution 2"
    },
    result = {};

Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => setValue(result, k, v));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the standard `Object.keys` like so :

```
 let qualifications = []
 const my_object = {
    "Qualifications[0].DegreeType": "Degree Type 1",
    "Qualifications[0].Classification": "Clasification 1",
    "Qualifications[0].CourseTitle": "Course Title 1",
    ...
 }


Object.keys(my_object).forEach(key => {
    //to access the index you could then do:
    const idx = Number(key.split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
    const sub_key = key.split('.')[1]
    //not here that i don't verify if the index exists
    if (!qualifications[idx]) qualifications[idx] = {}
    qualifications[idx][sub_key] = my_object[key]
})
```